# how can i get value fron the URL in python appengine?

Tags: python, android, url

if i have this URL in from python code on appengine

```
http://localhost:8080/blog/view/2f1cab5844fb432b8426ae666c4ac493
```

how can i get the value of the key : 2f1cab5844fb432b8426ae666c4ac493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the requested URL via `self.request`, assuming you're extending the standard `webapp.RequestHandler` class.  That will give you access to the path and query, and you should be able to extract the values you want from the path.

Here's some documentation on the Request object:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html

Answer (score 2):

@Herms answer will work, but you may prefer this instead:

In the code that creates your webapp instance, capture the key part of the URL with a regex, like:

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication( [
         (r'/blog/view/(\w+)', MyBlogViewHandler),
         ## others listed here...
         ])
```

...then code your handler class like this - the key you captured will be passed to your `get()` method as an argument:

```
class MyBlogViewHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self, key):
      # do something useful with the 'key' argument
```

Comment: No, key will be passed to your handler method as a string - in your example, you'll get the argument `'2f1cab5844fb432b8426ae666c4ac493'` passed in as the value of `key`.

Comment: Did not know you could do that. I like it.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing for a post? It does not seem to work for me.